# Configuring an IP address for SagePay Direct when using Windows Azure

Tags: azure, opayo

I've entered the IP address from the Windows Azure Portal (both the one specified in the website Dashboard or within the Manage Domains area) but when trying to use SagePay Direct it returns that it is not a valid IP address.

I eventually solved this by doing a "showpost" for SagePay and then having to tell me what the IP address is.

The problem is - how can I determine this IP address for myself? As I worry that the IP address could change in the future.

If I use "Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR")" (Classic ASP) it seems to return the local IP address of the webserver.

Answer (score 0):

what if you create a script or something that just returns the visitor IP address and make a request, get or post, to that script from your server?

Answer (score 0):

The IP Address that you see to use for your A records is not the outgoing IP Address used by Azure Websites. Hence why SagePay does not accept transactions from the website because it is an invalid IP Address.

Instead there are 4 IP Addresses that you need to add, and those 4 IP Addresses depend on what Scale Unit your site uses. 
The scale unit for your site can be found from the FTP Host Name for your Azure website. For example: ftp://waws-prod-blu-011.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net  - the scale unit is 'waws-prod-blu-011'

I then put that into Google, and a couple of azure maintenance articles came up. Scroll the article to you see your region, and then your scale unit and there are the 4 IP Addresses you need.

Please refer to [this azure maintenance article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fd53afb7-14b8-41ca-bfcb-305bdeea413e/maintenance-notice-upcoming-changes-to-increase-capacity-for-outbound-network-calls?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) for more information.